# Обработчик нажатия кнопки срабатывает просто так, со старта страницы без нажатия

Tags: javascript

Обработчик нажатия кнопки срабатывает просто так, со старта страницы без нажатия. В чем причина - не могу понять. Хелп! 
locationButton2 - обычная кнопка. 
mainTextArea - TextArea.

```
function startLocationCity(){
    document.getElementById('locationButton2').onclick = setTextInTextArea("qwe");
}

function setTextInTextArea(text){
    document.getElementById("mainTextArea").value = document.getElementById("mainTextArea").value + "\n" + text;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы вызываете функцию, когда передаете ее в onclick
замените

```
document.getElementById('locationButton2').onclick = setTextInTextArea("qwe");
```

на

```
document.getElementById('locationButton2').onclick = () =>setTextInTextArea("qwe");
```

Так вы обернете свою функцию в обертку, которая уже будет вызывать вашу функцию.

Успехов!

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло <3